# Attaching rowSelect event on dynamically created DHTMLX Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I am working with DHTMLX Grid and I am constructing multiple grid objects using a method like

**JS:**

```
function renderGrid(render_area, dataURL, skin, loop_index) {
    var scope = this;
    var grid_obj = loop_index + '_grid';
    grid_obj = new dhtmlXGridObject($(render_area).attr('id'));
    grid_obj.selMultiRows = true;
    grid_obj.imgURL = "codebase/imgs/";
    grid_obj.init();
    grid_obj.setSkin(skin);
    grid_obj.load(dataURL);
}
```

I am doing this using a jquery plugin.Now I want to attach 'RowSelect' event to all these dynamically created grids.

I thought of doing it using the grid object on HTML page and attaching the event there like this
`0_grid.attachEvent("onRowSelect",scope.clickEvent);`

but unfortunately I am unable to get these dynamically created grid objects on the HTML Page(0_grid is undefined on the HTML Page).

Glad if somebody can suggest me some good solution

Comment: just add to the renderGrid function the line grid_obj.attachEvent("onRowSelect",scope.clickEvent); you dont need the name to attach an event just the object which you already have

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery's .on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach the events to dynamically created elements. You would need to attach the event to a static element that is a parent of your grid elements.

```
parent.on("event", "selector", "data", handler());
```

Comment: thanx for the reply.But this handler would be the static handler.Actually grid allows handler based on the row id of the data.So by using the above option I would not be able to do the required.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, either attach the listener within `renderGrid` or outside of it. I removed the `loop_index` parameter as you don't need it:

Within:

```
function renderGrid(render_area, dataURL, skin) {
    var grid_obj = new dhtmlXGridObject($(render_area).attr('id'));

    grid_obj.selMultiRows = true;
    grid_obj.imgURL = 'codebase/imgs/';
    grid_obj.init();
    grid_obj.setSkin(skin);
    grid_obj.load(dataURL);
    grid.attachEvent('onRowSelect', function () {
        // Or instead of an anonymous function you could use this.clickEvent
    });
}
```

Outside (you need to return the grid object from `renderGrid`:

```
function renderGrid(render_area, dataURL, skin) {
    var grid_obj = new dhtmlXGridObject($(render_area).attr('id'));

    grid_obj.selMultiRows = true;
    grid_obj.imgURL = 'codebase/imgs/';
    grid_obj.init();
    grid_obj.setSkin(skin);
    grid_obj.load(dataURL);

    return grid_obj;
}

var grid = renderGrid($('#grid'), '/data.xml', 'dhx_skyblue');
grid.attachEvent('onRowSelect', function () {
    // Or instead of an anonymous function you could use this.clickEvent
});
```

If you want to attach the event listener inside of a loop I would recommend reading [this](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures) paragraph from JavaScript Garden first.